# Variable in implementation file

Tags: objective-c

I just started picking up objective c and I have been following a tutorial online.
In the tutorial, it set the NSMutableAray pointer in the implementation (.m file) in the curly brackets. 
I thought the pointer variable should be declared in the header file.
What is the reason / benefit of having the pointer variable in the implementation file in the curly brackets?

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
{
    NSMutableArray *_players;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide instance variable from header file in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103858/hide-instance-variable-from-header-file-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons for declaring instance variables in the `@implementation`:

1. The instance variable is private to the implementation, it is implicitly private, cannot be made public, and no even subclasses can see it. This restricts access from outside the implementation to the value of the instance variable, or to setting its value, to public (or protected) methods/properties declared in the interface.
2. It de-clutters the public `@interface` by removing details which are not relevant to the *user* of the class, but only to its implementation.

Originally Objective-C did not support declaring instance variable in the `@implementation`, but it has for a few versions of Xcode/clang by now. In old code you will still see instance variables in the `@interface`, but it is better in new code to declared them in the `@implementation`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Apparently so private interface is unavailable outside